# What are alternatives to "delegates" for passing data between controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, objective-c-blocks

Are there alternatives to "delegates" to pass back data from one controller to another?

Just seems like a lot of work implementing a delegate just to pass back the result from a child controller, back to the parent controller.  Is there not another method?  Are "blocks" one answer, and if so some example code would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use many ways:

1. Calling a method of the super controller, needs casting maybe
2. [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)
3. Simple [Key-Value-Observing](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/tag/key-value-observing/)
4. [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

**Example for for 1.**

*interface of your MainViewController: add a public method for the data to be passed*

```
- (void)newDataArrivedWithString:(NSString *)aString;
```

*MainViewController showing ChildController*

```
- (void)showChildController
{
    ChildController *childController = [[ChildController alloc] init];
    childController.mainViewController = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:childController animated:YES];

    [childController release];
}
```

*Child Controller header / interface: add a property for the mainViewController*

```
@class MainViewController;

@interface ChildController : UIViewController {
    MainViewController *mainViewController;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *mainViewController;
```

*Child Controller passing data to the MainViewController*

```
- (void)passDataToMainViewController
{
    NSString * someDataToPass = @"foo!";
    [self.mainViewController newDataArrivedWithString:someDataToPass];
}
```

Comment: thanks Nick - which is the most simple for just getting a result back from say a separate controller for date picking?  i.e. which would be simpler than a delegate (less lines of code) do you think?

Comment: The first solution is very easy. Just create a method with parameters which reflect your return data. Notifications are also easy. KVO is elegant and you should have a look at it.

Comment: thanks - I might try the 1st approach.  With KVO (just reading about it) not sure if it would be ideal, like if you're in the detailed controller and the user is changing the value but hasn't decided and finally hit save, all the intermediate changes in values I assume would unnecessarily be reflected back through the observer in the parent controller.  (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Oh, I just realized I'm not sure on how to capture the responses back in the master controller. Is there a "master controller becomes active" type method I need to override perhaps?   And then I would need to store which child controller I called before hand so I would know?

Comment: have marked as answer to my specific question, but should note that Matthew Frederick gives a good answer in terms of benefits of actually sticking with delegates

Comment: Yes the delegate pattern is good, but if you don't want to use it, just some alternatives here ;)

Answer (score 14):

Delegates aren't a lot of work, aren't a lot of code, and are commonly the most appropriate solution. In my opinion they're neither difficult nor messy.

**Five lines of code** in the child's interface. Before @interface:

```
@protocol MyUsefulDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)infoReturned:(id)objectReturned;
@end
```

Inside @interface:

```
id <MyUsefulDelegate> muDelegate;
```

After @inteface's @end:

```
@property (assign) id <MyUsefulDelegate> muDelegate;
```

**One line of code** in the child's implementation:

```
[[self muDelegate] infoReturned:yourReturnObject];
```

**One addition to an existing line of code** in the parent's interface:

```
@interface YourParentViewController : UIViewController <MyUsefulDelegate>
```

**Three lines of code** in the parent's implementation. Somewhere before you call the child:

```
[childVC setMuDelegate:self];
```

Anywhere in the implementation:

```
- (void)infoReturned:(id)objectReturned {
    // Do something with the returned value here
}
```

A total of nine lines of code, one of which is merely an addition to an existing line of code and one of which is a closing curly brace.

It's not as simple as a returning a value from a local method, say, but once you're used to the pattern it's super straightforward, and it has the power of allowing you do do all kinds of more complex stuff.

Comment: +1 Delegates are really simple to learn. You should take the time and do it right. Singleton pattern is useful too, but probably overkill for what you want to do.

Comment: would you recommend this approach over KVO and Notifications would you?

Comment: For the purpose you describe, a delegate is the most appropriate choice, imo. It's certainly more appropriate than notifications. Mind you, I love notifications, but they're really best for almost-entirely-uncoupled objects, as opposed to the loose coupling you have here. KVO is ok for this, but is more of a pattern where one object is actively watching for a change in another, as opposed to the more "reporting back" style of this delegation.

Comment: Tks Matthew - oh can I ask your view on use if blocks here? (per what Daniel said was possible). I haven't found any sample code yet on this one to compare it to the delegate option.

Comment: You could pass a block as long as you're careful with releasing the memory of any objects inside after popping the child, which you could potentially do in the parent's viewDidUnload, though you'd be carrying the object around in memory for the life of the parent. Not sure if there's any way to do it right after you no longer need it, without -- you guessed it -- using a delegate (or notification).

Answer (score 2):

KVO or notifications are the way to go in many cases, but delegation gives a very good foundation to build upon. If you plan on extending the relationship between the view controllers in the future, consider using delegation.

Blocks are not really relevant to the above, but in short - it is a technique introduced with iOS 4, where you pass around blocks of code as variables/ parameters. It is very powerful and has many uses. For example, here is how you enumerate objects in an array using a block:

```
[someArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSLog(@"obj descriptions is - %@", [obj description]); 
}];
```

The part from the `^` until the `}` is a block. Note that I've passed it in as parameter. Now, this block of code will be executed for every object in the array (i.e. output will be the description of each object).

Blocks are also very efficient performance-wise, and are used heavily in many new frameworks.

Apple's [blocks beginners guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/) is quite good.

Comment: I've started using blocks to avoid creating explicit delegate protocols in my recent iOS 4+ projects.  It's definitely the most succinct way to code this type of thing, but memory management gets a bit tricky if you aren't careful about the variables that your blocks reference (and hence retain).

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NSNotificationCenter` — [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: would this be simpler than using a delegate do you think?

Comment: absolutely I think it would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Folks pay a lot of attention the the V and the C in MVC, but often forget the M. If you've got a data model, you can pass it from one controller to the next. When one controller makes changes to the data stored in the model, all the other controllers that share the same model will automatically get the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might find using a singleton is practical. Just use it as a central storage for all your shared data.

Then throw in saving the state of your application too;)

Comment: Singletons are great in their appropriate place: app-wide data and methods. They're not the right place, though, for data that only needs to be transfered from a child view controller to a parent, in my opinion. That's not app-wide data, it's data specific to those two view controllers. Putting it in a singleton is not only storing the data at the wrong level of scope, it leads to bad memory management because the passed-back data will hang around in the singleton for the life of the app.