# Passing data between classes using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, class

I need some info about how to pass data between classes.. To be specific, I want to store in a class in an array some info, (using model store class), and then use it in another class..

Comment: You mean passing data from one instance to another, right?

Comment: I'm a big fan of using delegates.  Here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532486/what-are-alternatives-to-delegates-for-passing-data-between-controllers/5533707#5533707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted some alternatives to the delegate pattern in Q&A [What are alternatives to “delegates” for passing data between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532486/what-are-alternatives-to-delegates-for-passing-data-between-controllers/5532505#5532505).

Answer (score 10):

You can do like:

For example: you want to pass `Array` from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`.

Create `Array` in `SecondViewController` first and define it as property as in SecondViewController.h:

```
NSMutableArray *secondArr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *secondArr;
```

In SecondViewController.m:

```
@synthesize secondArr;
```

Then, for example, you want to pass `Array` when a button in `FirstViewController` is touched. 
In its action (create IBAction, link it with the button's `touchesUpInside`), you can set it to get the instance of your second view controller, for example:

```
secondViewController.secondArr = firstArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. just declare array(let array2) in second class(MYSecondView) and do not forget to set his propert and synthesize.
   and then go to first class in .h file and import class(#import "MySecondView") where you define array2.
2. create an object of second class(MySecondView *objMySecondView=[MySecondView alloc]init];) in your first class.
   then pass value to array2 from array of first class.
   like

   ```
   objMySecondView.array2 setObjectFromArray=array1;
   ```

Answer (score -4):

If you don't know how to do that, it's seems that you're at the very beginning of learning Objective-c and OO programming. So you better have some time to read about it

A good place to start is [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)