# Passing data from a table view to another when clicking a row in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a table view with 5 rows, each row have product name(UiLabel), product photo(UiImageView) and product price(UiLabel).

When clicking a row, it will be changed to a UiView that showing the product name(UiLabel), product photo(UiImageView) and product price(UiLabel), plus a product description(UiLabel).

I want to ask how to pass the data of product name, photos, price and description which is stored in `ProductListTableView.m`, from this table view to another view `ProductDetailView`?

ps: I guess I should write some code on method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to write code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`-

and follow this to how to pass data from one class to another - [Passing data between classes using Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703538/passing-data-between-classes-objective-c/5703638#5703638)

you can pass a `NSDictionary` obj from one class to another.