# Cannot get text from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

After had many research, I don't find solution.So that I decided post my question. I have an ** IBOutlet `UITextField *txtUsername` at `DetailViewController.h`. At `FormViewController` I  have a `UIScrollview`, and then I add [`self.scrollView addSubview:DetailView.view]`. The problem is when stand at `DetailViewController.m` I call `txtUsername.text` it return a nil value. Any suggestion?

Comment: You might choose to post code for analysis here!  I also think you mean IBOutlet, not UIOutlet.

Comment: as i see, you need to share objects between classes. take a look at at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703538/passing-data-between-classes-objective-c) question & links

Comment: Please post some relevant code as well, also are you using storyboard or XIBs ?

Comment: Do your textfield contains any value?Did you check??

Comment: I don't need to share objects between classes in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug many time I found the problem is:
At **FormViewController** I have method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Add new user";
        DetailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And method (Which had call at viewDidLoad)

```
-(void) loadViewBySegment {
[DetailView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:DetailView.view];

   }
```

and ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(save)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    if(user)
    {
        userDetailView.user = user;
    }
    [self loadViewBySegment];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

and

```
-(void)save{
[[userDetailView userDetailInstance] insertData];
}
```

And then at **DetailViewController** I create **insertData** function

```
-(void)insertData{
User *object = [[User alloc] init];
    object.Username = txtUsername.text;
    object.FullName = txtFullname.text;
    object.Title = txtTitle.text;
    object.Role = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[txtRole.text intValue]];
    object.UserInitial =txtInital.text;
    object.Status = YES;
    object.AddedTime = [NSDate date];
    object.UpdatedTime = [NSDate date];
    object.Phone = @"0949931124";
    object.Password = @"123456";

    [[DBManager sharedInstant] insertData:BUsers item:[object dictionary] target:self];
}
```

The reason why texfield.text is nil:
At **FormViewController** I call an instance of **DetailViewController** it's mean **DetailViewController** - **will be have new alloc init**. so that textfield's value will which had enter by user before will be reset.
The right way I need to do is: change the save function at **FormViewController**:

```
-(void)save{
[DetailView insertData];
}
```

P/S:**Lesson Learn** for me is: be careful when use Instace (Singleton Design partner).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to embed one view controller within another. I recommend using a [Container view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) and then loading `DetailViewController` into that. Simply adding the view, as you are in your code, is not going to be enough. You probably want all the behavior in `DetailViewController` to work.

Comment: How to do that?could you post the code for more clear?

Comment: The choices you made in your answer are sub-optimal. I still think a Container view controller is the appropriate choice here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html You should add a Container view controller to the scroll view.

Comment: Thank for your recommend. Yes it's a good way to do, but in my case, if I make change like that, I must do a lot of things with UI.